# Using a macro inside a loop condition

Tags: c++, function, syntax, macros

I am programing in C++ and I defined a variable as a macro, and I want to return a value from a function using the macro.

For some reason the compiler says that I have a syntax error.  I am using Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#define FACTOR 10;
int dosomthing(){
    return (FACTOR/2);
}
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

Comment: What exactly does the compiler say?

Comment: Don't put a semicolon at the end of `#define FACTOR 10;`

Comment: There is really no justification for using macros in C++ in 99% of cases. They are [4x evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.5).

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange error with #define in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704241/strange-error-with-define-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Macros are replaced. So in the end you'll get

```
return (10;/2);
```

Just remove the `;` from your macro and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5):

`static const int FACTOR = 10;` is a better way to do this in C++.

Comment: But change the name so it is not all uppercase. Otherwise it could get scrambled by a Macro :-)