# Strange error with #define in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf, c-preprocessor

I know that #define replaced before the compiling to real values. so why the first code here compile with no error, and the 2nd not?

the 1st;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   printf("bc");
   return 0;
}
```

the 2nd(not working);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define Str "bc";
int main()
{
   printf(Str);
   return 0;
}

error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

thank you for the answers, and sorry about my poor English...

Comment: Are you sure the first one is compiling? The error looks like because of the `;` after `"bc"` in your first example.

Comment: thank you, my mistake, i replace the two code blocks

Comment: Thank you every body, I forgot the semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `Str` macro evaluates to `"bc";` — the semicolon is included. So your macro expands to:

```
printf("bc";);
```

You do not need to follow a #define with a semicolon. They end at a newline, rather than at the semicolon like a C statement. It is confusing, I know; the C preprocessor is a strange beast and was invented before people knew better.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the second works and the first doesn't. The problem is the semicolon:

```
#define Str "bc";
                ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
#define Str "bc"
```

with your define after the substitution it will look like:

```
printf("bc";);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the first one is that `Str` is replaced with `"bc";`.

Change it to

```
#define Str "bc"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove ; where you define str. Because you will get printf("bc";);

Answer (score 1):

The first code does not compile because you need to remove the semicolon after the #define the 2nd code works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't work because these lines:

```
#define Str "bc";
printf(Str);
```

expand to this line:

```
printf("bc";);
```

You want:

```
#define Str "bc"
```