# Macro definition error in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define SOUND_SPEED 0.034;    
int rtt; //round trip time in microsecond
double distance;
distance = (double)(rtt*SOUND_SPEED)/2;
```

It complains error: expected expression before '/' token. Was is it bacause I can't use macro to define decimals or what?

Comment: +1 A silly mistake--which I ***still*** make once every few years :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange error with #define in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704241/strange-error-with-define-in-c)

Answer (score 9):

Drop the semicolon:

```
#define SOUND_SPEED 0.034; 
                         ^
```

If you keep it the generated code will look like this:

```
distance = (double)(rtt*SOUND_SPEED;)/2;
                                   ^
```

Comment: Its get more convincing to look at the pre-processor output, e.g. `gcc -E foo.c`

Answer (score 3):

```
#define SOUND_SPEED 0.034;
                         ^
```

Do not use the trailing `;`

Actually you should never terminate a macro with a `;`:

> PRE11-C. Do not conclude macro definitions with a semicolon 
>           https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE11-C.+Do+not+conclude+macro+definitions+with+a+semicolon

Answer (score 1):

You're using C, but you're trying to use a C++ style `//` comment. Depending on your compiler, that may not be allowed.

Edit: In fact, gcc -c89 -ansi gives *that exact error message* for a `//` comment and a totally different one for the extraneous `;` in the define.

Comment: @ouah From C99 they are, but older compilers may definitely fail on this code. Since the question didn't mention what compiler is used, I thought it worth a mention.

Comment: Honestly I even don't know any C89 compiler that doesn't support it as a default extension.

Comment: @ouah Sun's C compiler used to fail on it in the 90's, not sure if any current compilers in C89 mode do. But as I said, no mention of whether the compiler was even C89.

Comment: I have Sun C compiler (SolarisStudio 12.2, with cc 5.0) installed on my Linux box and I just tested it: `//` is accepted by default.

Comment: @ouah A // comment with gcc -c89 -ansi gives the error in the question `error: expected expression before ‘/’ token` while the semicolon in the define gives `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token` in any mode. The question refers to the / token one.

Comment: Ah, that would have been more immediately obvious had Kevin given us more info about the error like which line it was occurring on.