# Why is the value of i still 5

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro definition error in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524809/macro-definition-error-in-c)

I'm new to programming and hope someone can help me with this:

Why is it giving an output : 5 .
Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 5;

int main(){
int i=0;
i = max+1;
printf("\n%d",i);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the ';' behind the 5 and you're good to go.

Comment: Yeah macros are evil. You could write: `const int max = 5;`. It's safer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the macro has a semi-colon. Code is equivalent to:

```
i = 5; + 1;
```

Remove the semi-colon from the macro.

Comment: Well spotted. It had me scratching my head for a minute.

Answer (score 5):

The crucial point is

```
#define max 5;
```

When substituted by the preprocessor, this will become

```
i = 5; +1;
```

which assigns 5 to the variable `i` (the expression `+1;` has no effect).

You need to write

```
#define max 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a semicolon after your macro definition x=